# miktex installation on windows 10 64 bit fails

Tags: miktex

I'm trying to Install `miktex-portable.exe` on a windows 10 x64 machine. The log shows:

```
this is MiKTeX Setup Service 5.5 (MiKTeX 23.4)
starting installer...
Loading package database...
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: C:\MYMiktex\texmfs/install
package repository: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\mik6436
visiting repository C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\mik6436...
repository type: local package repository
loading package repository manifest...
package repository digest: 5b9637ea3c5dc872c6bc24d8ceb977df
going to install 16872 file(s) (198 package(s))
extracting files from amsfonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amsmath.tar.lzma...
extracting files from arabi.tar.lzma...
extracting files from atbegshi.tar.lzma...
extracting files from atveryend.tar.lzma...
extracting files from avantgar.cab...
extracting files from babel.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-english.tar.lzma...
extracting files from biber-windows-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from biblatex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bibtex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from blindtext.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bookman.cab...
extracting files from cbcoptic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cm.tar.lzma...
extracting files from courier.tar.lzma...
extracting files from csfonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from csplain.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dehyph.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dvipdfmx.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dvips.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ec.tar.lzma...
extracting files from elhyphen.tar.lzma...
extracting files from enctex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from environ.tar.lzma...
extracting files from epstopdf-pkg.tar.lzma...
extracting files from etoolbox.tar.lzma...
extracting files from everyshi.tar.lzma...
extracting files from fontconfig.tar.lzma...
extracting files from fontspec.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ghostscript.tar.lzma...
extracting files from glyphlist.tar.lzma...
extracting files from graphics.tar.lzma...
extracting files from graphics-cfg.tar.lzma...
extracting files from graphics-def.tar.lzma...
extracting files from helvetic.cab...
extracting files from hyperref.tar.lzma...
extracting files from hyph-utf8.tar.lzma...
extracting files from iftex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from knuth-lib.tar.lzma...
extracting files from l3backend.tar.lzma...
extracting files from l3kernel.tar.lzma...
extracting files from l3packages.tar.lzma...
extracting files from latex-firstaid.tar.lzma...
extracting files from latex-fonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from latex-tools.tar.lzma...
extracting files from listings.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lm.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ltxbase.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lualibs.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luaotfload.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luatex85.tar.lzma...
extracting files from make4ht.tar.lzma...
extracting files from metafont.tar.lzma...
extracting files from metapost.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-arctrl-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-asymptote-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-autosp-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-axohelp-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibarts-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex8bit-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bzip2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cairo-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-chktex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cjkutils-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-config-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-console-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-curl-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cweb-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-devnag-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dict-british.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dict-english.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dict-french.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dict-german.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-doc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvicopy-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipdfmx.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipdfmx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipng-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvips.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvips-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvisvgm-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-epstopdf-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-expat-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-findtexmf-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fmt-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fontconfig.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fontconfig-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fonts-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-freeglut-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-freetype2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fribidixetex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-gd-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ghostscript-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-graphite2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-gregorio-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-gsf2pk-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-harfbuzz-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-hitex-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-hunspell-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-icu-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-jpeg-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-kpathsea-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lacheck-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-latex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lcdf-typetools-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-libressl-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-log4cxx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lua53-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-luatex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-luatex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lzma-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-m-tx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-makeindex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-md5-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metafont.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metafont-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metapost-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mfware-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-misc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mktex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mo-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mpfr-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mpmcli-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mspack-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mthelp-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mtprint-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-omegaware-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-patgen-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pdftex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pdftex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pixman-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pmx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-png-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-poppler-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-popt-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-posix-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ps2pk-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-psutils-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ptex-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-qt5-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-runtime-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-synctex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tdsutil-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-teckit-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex2xindy-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex4ht.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex4ht-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texify-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texware-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texworks-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ttf2pk2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ucrt-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-upmendex-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-uriparser-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-vc140-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-web-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xetex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xindy-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xml2pmx-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-yap-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-zip-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-zlib-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-zzip-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from modes.tar.lzma...
extracting files from mptopdf.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ms.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ncntrsbk.cab...
extracting files from oberdiek.tar.lzma...
extracting files from palatino.cab...
extracting files from pdftex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from pdftexcmds.tar.lzma...
extracting files from pgf.tar.lzma...
extracting files from pgfplots.tar.lzma...
extracting files from plain.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ragged2e.tar.lzma...
extracting files from rsfs.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ruhyphen.tar.lzma...
extracting files from standalone.tar.lzma...
extracting files from symbol.cab...
extracting files from tcolorbox.tar.lzma...
extracting files from tetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from tex-ini-files.tar.lzma...
extracting files from tex4ht.tar.lzma...
extracting files from times.cab...
extracting files from trimspaces.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ukrhyph.tar.lzma...
extracting files from unicode-data.tar.lzma...
extracting files from url.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xcolor.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xkeyval.tar.lzma...
extracting files from zapfchan.cab...
extracting files from zapfding.cab...
updating package manifests (C:\MYMiktex\texmfs/install\miktex/config\package-manifests.ini)...
installed 6360 package manifests
visiting repository C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\mik6436...
repository type: local package repository
loading package repository manifest...
initexmf --principal=setup --portable=C:\MYMiktex\texmfs/install --admin --disable-installer --verbose:
15 [0x0000505c] INFO initexmf null - this is MiKTeX Configuration Utility 5.3 (MiKTeX 23.4)

15 [0x0000505c] INFO initexmf null - this process (18512) started by miktex-portable in directory C:\Installers\Miktex with command line: initexmf --principal=setup --portable=C:\MYMiktex\texmfs/install --admin --disable-installer --verbose

15 [0x0000505c] INFO trace.initexmf.core null - turning on administrator mode

15 [0x0000505c] INFO initexmf null - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup

15 [0x0000505c] INFO initexmf null - Creating portable setup...

Creating portable setup...
15 [0x0000505c] INFO initexmf null - this process (18512) finishes with exit code 0

miktex --admin --disable-installer --verbose fndb remove:

Sorry, but: option --admin only makes sense for a shared MiKTeX setup
Warning: The executed process did not succeed.
Warning: The executed process did not succeed.
mpm --register-components --admin --verbose:

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Package Manager" did not succeed for the following reason:

  Option --admin only makes sense for a shared MiKTeX setup.
log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (mpmcli).
log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.

An error occurred:
  source file: 
  source line: 0
  message: The executed process did not succeed.
  info: fileName="C:\MYMiktex\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64\mpm.exe", exitCode="1"
```

Tried rebooting etc. but no change.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The `--admin` flag seems to be the problem, so maybe don't execute it as admin.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the reply. Tried that - no success. There is no option during the install to make the installation for just me rather than any user. I wondered if that might be the problem since that is recommended in the instructions. But so far no go.